# How to merge dictionary in list with Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dictionary

I generated data from a form with this code:

```
time_schedule = []
f = request.form
for key in f.keys():
    for idx, value in enumerate(f.getlist(key), 1):
        time_schedule.append({key+str(idx): value})
```

Then I got this result when I `print` it:

```
[{'csrf_token1': 'Ijg2YWEyNDEwMWI3ZTE4NjYyNzBkNTEwYTZlMzRiYTM3MjY2ZTk2NDAi.XaGmZw.rMR9Q53hlAQV-Ul9X3PHT55TMxc'}, {'course_start_at1': '2019-10-26'}, {'schedule_day1': 'Sunday'}, {'schedule_day2': 'Saturday'}, {'start_at1': '01:00'}, {'start_at2': '03:00'}, {'end_at1': '02:00'}, {'end_at2': '04:00'}, {'step1': 'input_teacher_email'}]
```

Then I removed to unecesary value:

```
del time_schedule[0]
del time_schedule[0]
del time_schedule[-1]
```

Then I here is the value now:

```
[{'schedule_day1': 'Sunday'}, {'schedule_day2': 'Saturday'}, {'start_at1': '01:00'}, {'start_at2': '03:00'}, {'end_at1': '02:00'}, {'end_at2': '04:00'}]
```

Now I want to merge it to be like this:

```
[
    {'schedule_day1': 'Sunday', 'start_at1': '01:00', 'end_at1': '02:00'},
    {'schedule_day2': 'Saturday', 'start_at2': '03:00', 'end_at2': '04:00'},
]
```

But not sure how to do it in the best practice. Please, any answer, source or tutorial how do that will be appreciated..? :)

Comment: So you have done something?

Comment: This seems like you have a whole other problem to solve and somehow maneuvered into this mess which you now try to clean up. Why is your start-data so "weird"? Maybe tweak the algorithm that produces the start-data. Would that be possible?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the format of the data? For example are the schedules keys always at front, are they ordered by the digit?

Comment: I have edited my questions, sorry if still make confuse questions.

Comment: @GofyandKitty, can your post the output of `request.form.items()` ?

Comment: It looks like you got some cast weirdness along the way and as others suggested you should try to tweak your parser for example taking advantage of modules like `json` to decode data in the format you need.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, here is the output when I print it:
`print(request.form.items())`
`<generator object MultiDict.items at 0x7fe7ef569bf8>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
    {'schedule_day1': 'Sunday'},
    {'schedule_day2': 'Saturday'},
    {'start_at1': '01:00'},
    {'start_at2': '03:00'},
    {'end_at1': '02:00'},
    {'end_at2': '04:00'}
]


seen = defaultdict(dict)
for d in data:
    for name, value in d.items():
        key = re.search('(\d+)$', name).group()  # this is the key extractor
        seen[key][name] = value

result = list(seen.values())

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'schedule_day1': 'Sunday', 'start_at1': '01:00', 'end_at1': '02:00'}, {'schedule_day2': 'Saturday', 'start_at2': '03:00', 'end_at2': '04:00'}]
```

Or since you tagged pandas:

```
import pandas as pd   

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[item for d in data for item in d.items()], columns=['name', 'value'])
grouper = df.groupby(df.name.str.extract('(\d+)$').squeeze())
result = [dict(zip(group.name, group.value)) for _, group in grouper]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'schedule_day1': 'Sunday', 'start_at1': '01:00', 'end_at1': '02:00'}, {'schedule_day2': 'Saturday', 'start_at2': '03:00', 'end_at2': '04:00'}]
```

The key both approaches is to group by the last digits of each key of the dictionaries, in the first solutions this is done using the `seen` dictionary (actually a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), in the second using pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Answer (score 1):

So after your edit the situation looks as follows:

- for every key you are going through the values of that key
- where the values are sorted respectively
- basically you have sorted lists of values per key

My attempt would be to not concat the index with the string but to continue to use it as an index.

```
sched = {}
for key in f.keys():
    for idx, value in enumerate(f.getlist(key), 1):
        if idx not in sched:
            sched[idx] = {}
        sched[idx][key] = value
```

This should give you a dict where the key is your ascending index is the key and the value are is the dict you want. If you need a list you could transform it to one...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution to answer my question, that's good answer, but I have found the simple one, thanks, I have voted up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use my code (input the data in the function argument)

```
def merge(_list):
    my_list = [] #data my_list
    for data in _list: #foreach in _list
        pq = ''.join([a for a in data]) #get string
        try:
           number = int(pq[-1]) #get number of last string (schedule1 -> 1)
        except:
           print("List can't be decoded")
        try:
           my_list[number-1] += [data]
        except:
           my_list.append([data])
    for x in range(len(my_list)):
        sub = {} #data sub
        for n in my_list[x]:
            sub.update(n) #update dictionary n
        my_list[x] = sub
    return my_list #returning my_list
```

This is a little bit longer because this is so hard algorithm without any module.

To use this `merge` function

```
data = [{'schedule_day1': 'Sunday'}, {'schedule_day2': 'Saturday'}, {'start_at1': '01:00'}, {'start_at2': '03:00'}, {'end_at1': '02:00'}, {'end_at2': '04:00'}]
data = merge(data)
print(data) 
#print out [{'schedule_day1': 'Sunday', 'start_at1': '01:00', 'end_at1': '02:00'}, {'schedule_day2': 'Saturday', 'start_at2': '03:00', 'end_at2': '04:00'}]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution to answer my question, that's good answer, but I have found the simple one, thanks, I have voted your answer up.